# Make a dropdownmenu without a list in CSS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to make a dropdown menu with `CSS`. I know a little bit how to make it but the `HTML` structure is different.
My structure is like that:

[image]

So in the end I would like to have it work like that:
-When you hover over menu1, the first submenupanel should dropdown with its submenulink.

the `CSS` of  `submenu_panel` is looking like that:

```
   .submenu_panel {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: gray;
    height:0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Can anyone help me to make my dropdown menu?

This is a short version of it in jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/4bjk8opa/

Comment: can you put your code in http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: If you do know how to do it with a list, it's the same thing. But why can't you use a list ? It's better (semantically speaking).

Answer (score 3):

Will this work with you.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spliter/vWDvy/)

```
 ul > li {display: block; float: left; margin-right: 10px; position: relative; background: Red; padding: 0.5em; line-height: 1em}
ul ul {display: none; width: 150px; position:absolute; top: 2em; left: 0}
ul ul > li {float: none;}
ul > li:hover > ul,
ul > a:hover + ul {display: block}
```

Comment: But do you know how I have to do it when I don't use a list?

Answer (score 0):

You'll either have to change your HTML structure or use JavaScript to achieve this. You're also declaring `height` twice for your `.submenu_panel`.

Steevan's Fiddle shows how you'd have to change your structure to make it work with pure CSS.

To make it work with jQuery, add an ID to the link you want to show `#pn1Submenu` when hovered, in this case I've used "target":

JS:

```
    $('#target').on('click', function() {
        $('#pn1Submenu').show();
    });
```

HTML:

```
    <a href="/" id="target" class="menu_link"...
```

Comment: Yep, I haven't had time to make a codepen or anything to test it. It should be `function () {...` and the last line should be `});`